# Pass Class method in a functions aruguments to call within the function

Tags: javascript, function, class, arguments

I want to pass a class method into a function and call that method inside that function. Here is the code:

```
class Cube {
    constructor() { //setup the cube and if using a previous cube, setup with that
        this.white = 'white'
    }
    changeColour(){
        this.white = 'yellow'
    }
}

const cubeClass = new Cube()

function change(classMethod){
    classMethod()
}
change(cubeClass.changeColour)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'white')
```

I want it to be able to change the colour in the class, from calling the change function, so it can change it from white to yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind `this` to the context of the `changeColour` method to the `cubeClass` object:

```
change(cubeClass.changeColour.bind(cubeClass));
```

This will ensure that when the `changeColour` method is called within the `change` function, the context is correctly set to `cubeClass`, allowing the method to access and modify the `white` property.

Answer (score 0):

Learn what is `this` in JS. That's a context under a function is called.
In your code you lose the context here:

```
change(cubeClass.changeColour);
```

You pass a method as an argument but not its class instance.
There're 2 fixes:

1. bind the class instance to your argument:

```
change(cubeClass.changeColour.bind(cubeClass);
```

2. a more cleaner way is to provide a wrapper function where the context is defined:

```
change(() => cubeClass.changeColor());
```